# Proof this Endomorphism has an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}, \Phi:\mathbb{R}^7\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^7$ be an endomorphism,
Proof that there exists an eigenvalue of $\Phi$
I know that every function with an odd degree takes on the value 0. But how can I prove this algebraically? Can I use the fundamental Theorem of Algebra, even if the field is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Usually, a function $f$ is called odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$ and then of course $f(0) = 0$, but this is not what this is about. In your case, you want a zero for the characteristic polynomial which has odd degree (note the difference: $x^7-1$ does not define an odd function). The fundamental theorem of algebra is one way to do this but this seems a bit overkill to me. Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Yes, I know this theorem, but I think that my Prof. doesn't want us to solve it with that theorem because we had this in Calculus.

Comment: By ithe ntermediate value theorem you get the existence of a real eigenvalue. I do not see any reason for avoiding analytical methods while answering your question.